# How to avoid & in XML ?

Tags: php, xml, curl, encoding

I am trying to send all data to xml through php. But somehow XML parses the data and in Password it finds `&` and replaces it with `&amp;` after that data is posted through Curl. So is there any method / technique to avoid `&` in xml. Or it goes as it is. I am tried almost all encoding functions.

Comment: `&` _should_ be encoded aa `&amp;` in xml, why does the receiving end have problems with this? Surely they don't require invalid XML (he said, hopefully, but with dreadful memories of atrocities past...).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [CDATA Section](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) to make it leave the ampersand unchanged.

Comment: as there is password field i am unable use CDATA. becoz CDATA unable to parse it and becoz of which authentication is failed.

Answer (score 0):

In the normal course of events, & in the data is encoded as `&amp;` in the XML, and the XML parser decodes this and presents it as `&` to the application. If the application (curl?) is seeing it as `&amp;` this is either because it has been double-escaped in the XML (as `&amp;amp;`) or because it is not being read using a real XML parser.

Comment: Yes Michael you seems to be true .. it shows me &amp;amp; but dnt know from where he get second amp;

Comment: Well, you have two choices. Either find out who misencoded the data and fix the problem at source, or detect and repair the problem downstream. (Either way, accepting the answer would be courteous.)