# Displaying XML using CSS: How to handle &nbsp?

Tags: css, xml, dtd

I'm dealing with a lot of .xml files. (Millions - an .xml formatted dump of Wikipedia) and they're a lot more unreadable than I imagined.

For the time being, I've written a .css file to display them in a readable manner in a browser, and wrote a script to plug a reference to this .css into all the files.

(I know there's other solutions, like XSLT - but all the information I found made it seem document-level which didn't suit - I'm really trying not to expand the size of these files if possible)

The .css works fine for *some* of the files, but many contain entities like *&nbsp* and I get errors like:

"XML Parsing Error: undefined entity" with a nice little illustration pointing to *&nbsp* or it's kin within a quote.

There is an articles.dtd file, which seems like it should connect the dots ( keyword -> Unicode ) for the browser. It is referenced in each file like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "../article.dtd">
```

and contains a lot of entries like:

```
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;"> <!-- no-break space = non-breaking space,
                              U+00A0 ISOnum -->
```

but either I'm entirely misunderstanding what this file is for, or it's not working correctly.

In any case; How can I make these documents display; Either by:

- displaying the entities (like "&nbSp" as plain-text)
- removing the entities altogether (by any means other than just a linear search/removal of them in the actual files)
- Interpreting the entities as unicode, as they were intended

Naturally, the latter being preferable; absolutely ideally, by referencing some sort of external file that maps identities to Unicode (if that's not what the articles.dtd file is for....)

EDIT: I'm not working with a powerful machine here.. extracting the .rars took days. Any sort of edits to each file would take a very long time.

Comment: Aside from all other similar questions, this question was asked **just 2 hours ago** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341862/how-to-avoid-in-xml

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found that question, among others; but it's solution, applied to my situation, only offers a round-about alternative to my last-ditch option of linearly searching/removing the entities. 
I felt the context of my question was different enough to warrant it's own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I've since solved my problem:  if it helps anyone in future:

It turned out the guts of my problem was that external .dtd files are totally deprecated.

The function of the .dtd was in fact to declare the entities I was having trouble with(  etc) as I thought; but because external .dtd files are not supported by browsers any more (the browsers simply don't fetch/parse them - and the only way to force them to depends on files in the install of the browser on the client-machine) the entities went undeclared.

I had sourced an .XML collection that was simply too old to be up to standards; without realizing it.

The solution best for my circumstances turned out to be lazy-processing of each file as it was requested. with a simple flag to differentiate processed from not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very good way, just workaround: try to replace `&nbsp;` with `&#160;`

Comment: yes, this is what I was alluding to when I said "removing entities altogether". 
keep in mind I have millions of un-indexed files here. Any sort of find-replace would take a long time...